# LINQ to Active Directory for accessible files

Tags: c#, linq, active-directory

I am new to active directory and I am trying to put together a query that will return list of users and groups who have permissions to read the contents of any accessible file.
I can not find any samples that deal with files. So I am at a lost on how to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help - looks like it's what you're trying to do:

[How to programmatically set NTFS file system folder permissions by using Active Directory Service Interfaces in Microsoft Visual C#](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/899553)

Basically, the files are "protected" by ACL - Access Control Lists - which is basically what you see in the UI tool - the "read", "modify", "full control" permissions etc. Those ACL's contain the user or group in question, and the permission to be set or removed.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this [CodePlex project](http://www.codeplex.com/LINQtoAD) - looks like it's doing exactly what you want.

Comment: I am using this project; that not the problem. All the sample that I can find only deal with users and groups with some of their properties. I can not find any samples or doc. that show how accessible files relate to users and groups.